# Two time difference show Error in Laravel Carbon

Tags: laravel, php-carbon

I tried to show difference between two time according to employee 
   attendance late or early enter in office. 
I tried to use as usual Carbon procedure which laravel use like diffInMinutes() or diffInHours(). 
 But its generate a Fatal-Error which is unexpected for me. 
Note : Carbon already use in top of the controller like below : 
use Carbon\Carbon;

 I also tried to use

```
 protected $dates = ['created_at', 'updated_at','enter_time'];
```

```
   $official_Entry_time = Carbon::parse('10:00:00 AM')->format("H:i:s A");
   /* 
     $data->enter_time contain actual entry time. retrieve from database.
    Guess enter time is : $data->enter_time = '12:35:20 PM';
  */
   $Enter_Time = Carbon::parse($data->enter_time)->format("H:i:s A"); 
   $lateOrEarly = $official_Entry_time->diffInMinutes($Enter_Time);
   echo $lateOrEarly;
```

I expected the output 22 minutes or other. but its showing 'Call to a member function diffInMinutes() on string'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You formatting the Carbon object to a string. Just use the Carbon object

```
$official_Entry_time = Carbon::parse('10:00:00 AM');

$Enter_Time = Carbon::parse($data->enter_time);

$lateOrEarly = $official_Entry_time->diffInMinutes($Enter_Time);

echo $lateOrEarly;
```

Comment: please mark as the answer if this works for you. :)

Answer (score 2):

remove `format()` and then try it .. it's working for me

```
 $official_Entry_time = Carbon::parse('10:00:00 AM');
    /* 
      $data->enter_time contain actual entry time. retrieve from database.
     Guess enter time is : $data->enter_time = '12:35:20 PM';
   */
    $Enter_Time = Carbon::parse('12:35:20 PM');
    $lateOrEarly = $official_Entry_time->diffInMinutes($Enter_Time);
    echo $lateOrEarly;
```